# Defining random variable which follows multiple distribution by case

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

It might be a stupid question but, I want to ask that it is possible to define a special random variable described as follow,

Let $Y$ to be a random variable which I want to define. Then,

$$
Y \sim \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            N_{1}(\mu_{1}, \sigma_{1}) & \quad \text{with probability of 0.3} \\
            N_{2}(\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2}) & \quad \text{with probability of 0.5} \\
            N_{3}(\mu_{3}, \sigma_{3}) & \quad \text{with probability of 0.2} \\
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

1. Is it possible to define $Y$ as a random variable following above probability distribution?
2. If possible, how can I get $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$? Can I calculate the $E(Y)$ in an intuitive way like the below or there is another right way to calculate the expectation and variation?

$$
E(Y) = 0.3E(N_{1}) + 0.5E(N_{2}) + 0.2E(N_{3})$$

3. If there is any theory or keyword about this, please let me know about it. I tried to google about my problem but I couldn't because I don't know what to search.

I always appreciate so much for your sincere help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology is that $Y$ is a [mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution). More precisely, it is a finite mixture of the r.v.s $N_1,N_2,N_3$ with weights $0.3,0.5,0.2$. The probability density of $Y$ is then simply the mixture density
$$f_Y(y)=0.3f_{N_1}(y)+0.5f_{N_2}(y)+0.2f_{N_3}(y).$$
That immediately implies your conjecture for $E(Y)$, and indeed in general one has $$E[H(Y)]=0.3E[H(N_1)]+0.5E[H(N_2)]+0.2E[H(N_3)]$$
for any function $H(\cdot)$ with finite expectated value. (For proof and applications, see the Wikipedia link above.)

Comment: Thanks! Now I am going to study about mixture distribution. By the way, I got the large number of data of male's height for 3 different regions. And all of them turns out to be following normal distribution. And there is a group which consist of 30% of people from A region, 50% of people from B region and 20% of people from C region. The reason I asked the question initially was, I wanted to know whether the approach "mixture distribution" can be a rational way to infer the average height of group or not. What do you think of it? Is there anything I missed?

Comment: That sounds reasonable and I don't think you missed anything. I would underline that your specific type of mixture distribution is of "Mixtures within a parametric family" type which is mentioned in that Wikipedia article: the three populations are all normally distributed, but with different parameters.